# Looping through ..array push in php

Tags: php, json

```
$query = "SELECT * from tblTwigUsers;";
    $result = mysqli_query ($con,$query);

if (mysqli_num_rows($result)>0)
    {
        $response = array();
        $code = "profile_true";
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
        {
            array_push    ($response,array("code"=>$code,"fldUser_Id"=>$row[0],"fldUser_UserName"=>$row[2]));   
            echo json_encode(array("server_resposnse"=>$response));
        }
    }
else
    {   
        $response = array();
        $code = "profile_false";
        $message = "failed to get user profile info...";
        array_push ($response,array("code"=>$code,"message"=>$message));
        echo json_encode(array("server_resposnse"=>$response));  
    }
```

Result

```
    {
    "server_resposnse": [{
        "code": "profile_true",
        "fldUser_Id": "1",
        "fldUser_UserName": "sohan"
    }]
} {
    "server_resposnse": [{
        "code": "profile_true",
        "fldUser_Id": "1",
        "fldUser_UserName": "sohan"
    }, {
        "code": "profile_true",
        "fldUser_Id": "2",
        "fldUser_UserName": "sonal"
    }]
} {
    "server_resposnse": [{
        "code": "profile_true",
        "fldUser_Id": "1",
        "fldUser_UserName": "sohan"
    }, {
        "code": "profile_true",
        "fldUser_Id": "2",
        "fldUser_UserName": "sonal"
    }, {
        "code": "profile_true",
        "fldUser_Id": "3",
        "fldUser_UserName": "amit"
    }]
} {
    "server_resposnse": [{
        "code": "profile_true",
        "fldUser_Id": "1",
        "fldUser_UserName": "sohan"
    }, {
        "code": "profile_true",
        "fldUser_Id": "2",
        "fldUser_UserName": "sonal"
    }, {
        "code": "profile_true",
        "fldUser_Id": "3",
        "fldUser_UserName": "amit"
    }, {
        "code": "profile_true",
        "fldUser_Id": "4",
        "fldUser_UserName": "rajiv"
    }]
}
```

Why is the data repeating ? 
The 4th result is the correct one , I need that ? How to get it?
Help appreciated,

Thx,
Sohan

Comment: If you want the 4th result then add a `WHERE` clause in your `SELECT` query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't `echo json_encode()` inside the loop, because then you'll print the JSON multiple times, each one being a little longer than the previous one. Wait until after the loop is done.

```
$response = array();
if (mysqli_num_rows($result)>0)
{
    $code = "profile_true";
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {
        array_push($response,array("code"=>$code,"fldUser_Id"=>$row[0],"fldUser_UserName"=>$row[2]));   
    }
}
else
{   
    $code = "profile_false";
    $message = "failed to get user profile info...";
    array_push($response,array("code"=>$code,"message"=>$message)); 
}
echo json_encode(array("server_resposnse"=>$response));
```

BTW, you misspelled "response" in `"server_responsnse"`. Make sure you use the same spelling here and in the code that processes the JSON.

Also, `array_push($array, $value);` can be written more idiomatically as `$array[] = $value;`